# Is it possible to compile an FFmpeg filter without recompiling

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to write my own filter.  Is it possible to compile the filter all by itself so I don't have to recompile FFMpeg with it every time?  If so, how do I register the filter with FFMpeg once it has been recompiled?

Comment: If you don't clean the build it'll recompile only what it needs to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

+What the comment states, as far as I know only the library (i.e. libavfilter) needs to be compiled once when you added new files, later updates and compiling only the updated object file will be compiled. Hope that helps.